# Flask inside docker does not get json requests

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

My flask application, whose works inside a docker container, does not get json requests.
When I sent json request I get tuple in response, looks like that(Ellipsis, Ellipsis)

My endpoint

```
class WhoisInfo(Resource):
    def post(self):
        if request.method == "POST":
           logger.debug("got request method POST")
        if request.is_json:
            logger.debug("is json")
            logger.debug(request.args.get('host'))
            logger.debug(request.get_data())
    return {"error": "Not information about this zone "}, 400
api_v1.add_resource(WhoisInfo, "/api/whois/")
```

debug output

```
backend_1  | 2021-10-03 13:03:30.582 | DEBUG    | api.views:post:53 - got request method POST
backend_1  | 2021-10-03 13:03:30.583 | DEBUG    | api.views:post:55 - is json
backend_1  | 2021-10-03 13:03:30.583 | DEBUG    | api.views:post:56 - (Ellipsis, Ellipsis)
backend_1  | 2021-10-03 13:03:30.583 | DEBUG    | api.views:post:57 - b'{"host": "8.8.8.8"}'
```

My request

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:80/api/whois/"

payload={"host": "8.8.8.8"}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Comment: Instead of `data=payload` use `json=payload` and remove your custom headers. Then in your view use `request.json`.

Comment: I did it, but error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem come from the wrong Flask version, I used python3.8 and Flask 0.10.1, I changed Flask version to 2.0.2 and everything works.

Comment: It was 100% because of this there was a conflict between the old version of flask and python. In any case, I fixed it this way, and the docker had nothing to do with it, I created a clean environment on my local machine and got exactly the same error, that's when I realized that my packages were the problem.